# Wireguard peer sharing

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

I have the following setup:

- a lokal NAS server in my home network with a dynamic IP. Lets call it **backup server**
- multiple rented servers in a data center with static IPs. Lets call them **server 1-x**
- multiple mobile and desktop clients with dynamic IPs in different networks (might be same as **backup server**). Lets call them **clients 1-x**

I have successfully setup a wireguard connection between the **backup server** and the online **servers 1-x**. As I understood it this is possible because of the build in roaming. What I would like to setup is a way for the **clients** to connect to the **backup server**. I was able to establish a connection between **clients** and **servers**. Is there a two-way-roaming option? Can I setup the **servers** to automatically share their peering information with clients, so they can establish a direct connection?

`wg show` on **backup server**:

```
# wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 33385

peer: xyz
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
  allowed ips: 10.66.66.3/32, fd42:42:42::3/128
  latest handshake: 13 seconds ago
  transfer: 62.32 MiB received, 224.89 MiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

peer: xyz
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194
  allowed ips: 10.66.66.1/32, fd42:42:42::1/128
  latest handshake: 56 seconds ago
  transfer: 6.09 GiB received, 512.43 MiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

`wg show` on one of **servers**:

```
# wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: xxx  
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 1194

peer: xyz
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33385
  allowed ips: 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
  latest handshake: 59 seconds ago
  transfer: 2.69 GiB received, 52.58 GiB sent
```

Comment: "share their peering" is a kind of dynamic routing protocol. Take a look at: https://www.wireguard.com/todo/

Comment: Do I understand correctly: the `endpoint` pointing to **backup server** needs to be exchanged between **servers** and **clients**? or am I missing something? Apparently wireguard does not support this out-of-the-box. I guess I should write a simple script myself then?